# During MSI Upgrade through GPO(Group Policy Object) previous version's MST property is getting picked

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, gpo

> I am trying to upgrade the software through GPO. The previous
> installed version is 3.6.2. Now I am trying to install version 3.8.2
>
> When I installed the version 3.6.2 at that time I prepared the
> MST(transform) file and uploaded as a modification in GPO package. In
> this MST file I changed one of the property called as JSONFILEPATH and
> gave some shared location path as a value to it. I am using this
> property in command line argument while running one of the exe which
> is part of installer itself. I have set the custom action in
> InstallShield to run the exe and used JSONFILEPATH as command line
> parameter.
>
> Now during the upgrade again I prepared the MST file for version 3.8.2
> and gave the new value to property JSON file path. Loaded the MST file
> as a modification and upgraded the software.

**Now the problem is while upgrade ideally it should have picked the JSONFILEPATH value of MST 3.8.2. However it's still somehow using the value of version 3.6.2**

Comment: instead of define the property TRANSFORMS `Setup.exe /s /v"/qn TRANSFORMS=MyTransform382.MST"`, you can try to define the property JSONFILEPATH  directly in the command line : `Setup.exe /s /v"/qn JSONFILEPATH=\\Server\Share\MyFile.json"`